# Local Tomcat 7 GZIP compression not working

Tags: tomcat

I saw the the questions about the same problem. But I could't solve this.

I replaced this code:

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

with the:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"connectionTimeout="20000" 
            redirectPort="8443"                        
        compression="on" 
    compressionMinSize="2048" 
    nocompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
    compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css, text/javascript,text/json, application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/json" />
```

in  tomcat's conf/server.xml file. But I couldn't see any "Content-Encoding gzip" header in requests. I request to the spring web application with the 8080 port. Does this compressing method require only by tomcat side? Or I need to add something to the application? If not what is the problem? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Set `compression="force"` (instead of `compression="on"`).